# ASP.NET Core app deployment to AWS Beanstalk using GitHub Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, github, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to build a CD pipeline using the GitHub Actions and AWS Beanstalk (mac) for my ASP.NET Core app. I have configured the YML file as follows:

```
name: Deploy AWS

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
   
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.301
    
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal

    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -o '${{ github.workspace }}/out'
  
    - name: Zip Package
      run: |
        cd ${{ github.workspace }}/out 
        zip -r ${{ github.workspace }}/out.zip *
    - name: Deploy to EB
      uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v13
      with:
        aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        application_name: demovideo
        environment_name: demovideo-dev
        region: us-east-2
        version_label: ${{ github.run_id }}
        version_description: ${{ github.sha }}
        deployment_package: ${{ github.workspace }}/out.zip
```

But I get an error on github about the version failure. This is the current log:

```
23:53:45 ERROR: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed
23:53:46 ERROR: [Instance: i-094e9d57f5e05c25c ConfigSet: Infra-WriteRuntimeConfig, Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild, Hook-PreAppDeploy, Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild, Hook-EnactAppDeploy, Hook-PostAppDeploy] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: null.
23:53:46 INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
23:53:46 ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-094e9d57f5e05c25c'. Aborting the operation.
23:53:46 ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
23:53:46 ERROR: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
23:53:56 ERROR: Deployment failed! Current State: Version: v20210310030618, Health: Red, Health Status: Degraded
Error: Deployment failed: Error: Deployment failed! Current State: Version: v20210310030618, Health: Red, Health Status: Degraded
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to add [Procfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-linux-procfile.html) to specify the application you are using

ex:

```
web: dotnet exec ./Application.dll --urls http://0.0.0.0:5000/
```

and for publish command try below command:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o '${{ github.workspace }}/out' -r linux-x64 --self-contained false
```